# Can't make products inline-blocks on category page Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Somehow the category page is showing my products vertically instead of e.g. 4 products horizontal and then starts again. I believe the issue is at some PHP file, that gives each product a div with 100%width, thus ignoring my CSS to be inline-block and 25% width(products on category page). 


Here's an explanation picture of what i mean, and how I "fixed" it on Chrome Inspector Tool. [image: ![Explaination picture](http://atlanticwool.com/UPLOADASTHELGALOVE.jpg).]


Am I to look at wrapper-start.php file or? (keep in mind, I don't have any experience with PHP, and I've tried to rename files to see where error sort'of is)
That code is as following:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

$template = get_option( 'template' );

switch( $template ) {
case 'twentyeleven' :
    echo '<div id="primary"><div id="content" role="main">';
    break;
case 'twentytwelve' :
    echo '<div id="primary" class="site-content"><div id="content" role="main">';
    break;
case 'twentythirteen' :
    echo '<div id="primary" class="site-content"><div id="content" role="main" class="entry-content twentythirteen">';
    break;
case 'twentyfourteen' :
    echo '<div id="primary" class="content-area"><div id="content" role="main" class="site-content twentyfourteen"><div class="tfwc">';
    break;
default :
    echo '<div id="main-container" class="container"><div class="row" style="padding: 0px 15px; width:100%; display:inline-block;">';
    break;
}
```

Or is it the content-product_cat.php?

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $woocommerce_loop;

// Store loop count we're currently on
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] ) )
    $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = 0;

// Store column count for displaying the grid
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) )
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );

// Increase loop count
$woocommerce_loop['loop']++;
?>
<li class="product-category product<?php
    if ( ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 0 || $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 1 )
        echo ' first';
    if ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 0 )
        echo ' last';
    ?>">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory', $category ); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $category->slug, 'product_cat' ); ?>">

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_subcategory_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );
        ?>

        <h3>
            <?php
                echo $category->name;

                if ( $category->count > 0 )
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );
            ?>
        </h3>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_subcategory_title hook
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', $category );
        ?>

    </a>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', $category ); ?>

</li>
```

Here's [A link to the website/category page](http://atlanticwool.com/product-category/brown-rugs/).

Comment: Welcome back Runiwinther. I see you are still stuck on this issue and I still advise reverting to the default WooCommerce templates. By default the products are in an unordered list and float in columns of 4, which seems to be what you are going for. Your markup looks all wrong to me, with columns not properly enclosed in rows.

Comment: PS- `content-product_cat.php` is the template for displaying a category in the case where the category is configured to list its sub-categories. Your link shows products in the category archive, so I assume this template is not in play. You should be using `content-product.php`, but I also guess that your `loop-start.php` and `loop-end.php` have been modified.

Comment: Hi again Helga! 
I've done so now, and the CSS/design of the category is all over now, BUT, I will try to manually overwrite one-by-one php file by the old one's, see where the problem truly exempts from, I will tell you later what my findings are. 
Thanks again :).

Comment: In-lined the image, improved formatting